# Center an Item on Canvas using CustomPaint

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've tried to center items in a `Canvas` using the `CustomPainter` in Flutter, ranging from TextPaints to even plain circles.

Normally, when centering a custom paint, I'd set the `Offset` to `Offset(size.width/2, size.height/2)`. But it's not working and my item is drawn towards the bottom right of the canvas.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Container(
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Container(
          width: constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
          height: constraints.widthConstraints().maxHeight,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: FollowPainter(),
          ),
        );
      }),
    ));
  }
}

class FollowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static final fill = Paint()..color = Colors.black;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
        style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
        text: 'Hello World');
    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout();
    tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

I suspect that the problem could be the fact that I'm starting the drawing from that Offset, instead of drawing from the center.

So how can I center a drawn widget in the CustomPainter?

Comment: you need to subtract the half-size of `TextPainter` from `Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)`

Comment: But how can I get the half size?

Comment: half-size = size / 2

Comment: No, I'm talking about the size of the TextPainter. tp.layout(); doesn't allow you to input an offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect that the problem could be the fact that I'm starting the drawing from that Offset, instead of drawing from the center.

You're right, just subtract half of the width of the text from width and half of its height from height.

```
tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(size.width / 2 - tp.width / 2, size.height / 2 - tp.height / 2));
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got the assertion error !_needsLayout is not true :/

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by adding tp.layout(). Thanks :D

Comment: @WilsonWilson you had the tp.layout() in your original code :)

Comment: I know, I accidentally removed it :)